# Receive "Request failed with status code 502 nginx in nextjs typescript

Tags: typescript, docker, kubernetes, next.js, nginx-ingress

I have configured Next.js typescript with Kubernetes NGINX Ingress but at the moment of accessing it it sends me `502` to specific routes but not to the entire project vgr .: in `/test` it works fine but in `/login` it does not work. I don't know how to reproduce the error to know what is happening. I don't know if Kubernetes or Docker is misconfigured.

[image]
[image]
[image]

full config in [this](https://github.com/slemac/kuber) GitHub repository

Comment: In both cases for `/test` and `/login` you use the same rule in Ingress for `client-srv` service?

Comment: yes, check: 
- path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000

Comment: Please provide information about versions of your Ingress controller and Kubernetes, information about some resources - run this command `kubectl get pods,svc,ep` Are you able to perform requests for specific paths from kubernetes pod?

Comment: the ingress controller is: controller-v1.1.0.
i used kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
aditional info i have added in post

Comment: Can you add logs from NGINX Ingress Controller and also containing information for your requests to /test and /login paths? Also, previously I asked you about requests right from your kubernetes pod (without Ingress involvement) to check if your services works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndrewSkorkin. Thanks to your comments I have been able to solve it.

Comment: Nice to hear it. Can you post an answer with solution that helped to solve your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).